# hibernate relations in angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, hibernate, one-to-one

I have two classes with one to one relation I retrieved their data and show them in html by rest service and angularJS all thing is fine but when I try to use  {{asset.airport.id}} 
to display  airport id in asset page I get nothing I want to know how can i deal with hibernate relations in angularjs  onetoone ,onetomany and manytomany.

his is code

```
 <tr ng-repeat="asset in assets">
                    <td>{{asset.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.assetName}}</td>
                    <td>{{asset.airport.id}}</td>
  <tr>
```

Asset class

```
public class Asset implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String assetName;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "asset",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
 private Airport airport;
```

Airport Class

```
 public class Airport implements Serializable {
 @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "iata_code")
private String iatacode;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Asset asset;
```

Comment: You marked the field with JsonIgnore. So it's not serialized to JSON.

Comment: I get this error when remove this annotation  Error: [$resource:badcfg] Error in resource configuration. Expected response to contain an array but got an object

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
@JsonBackReference
@JsonManagedReference
```

Check this links for understanding how it works

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Cheers!